# how can i get the Model from an ViewResult in a asp.net mvc unittest?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

i call a controller action in a unit test.

```
 ViewResult result = c.Index(null,null) as ViewResult;
```

I cast the result to a ViewResult, because that is what i'm returning in the controller:

```
return View(model);
```

But how can i access this model variable in my unit test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
// Arrange
var c = new MyController();

//Act
var result = c.Index(null,null);
var model = result.ViewData.Model; 

//Assert
Assert("model is what you want");
```

Comment: it's in the viewdata! Thanks, didn't look there.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you the excellent [MVContrib test helper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper). Your test might look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SomeTest()
{
    // arrange
    var p1 = "foo";
    var p2 = "bar";

    // act
    var actual = controller.Index(p1, p2);

    // assert
    actual
        .AssertViewRendered() // make sure the right view has been returned
        .WithViewData<SomeViewData>(); // make sure the view data is of correct type
}
```

You can also assert on properties of the model

```
actual
    .AssertViewRendered()
    .WithViewData<SomeViewData>()
    .SomeProp
    .ShouldEqual("some expected value");
```

Comment: Instead of`.ShouldEqual("some expected value");`
did you mean `.ShouldBe("some expected value");` ?